# `requirements.txt` dependencies, getting only high level dependencies

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I have a three python projects A, B and C. Each depending on each other.

> How can I now "clean up" my requirements.txt that only the high level
>   dependencies that are required at this "level" are there.

## Example

### **A** requirements:

boto3==1.2.4

### **B** requirements:

A==0.0.1
***boto3==1.2.4***
cookiecutter==1.4.0

### **C** requirements:

B==0.0.1
slacker==0.9.9
***boto3==1.2.4***
***cookiecutter==1.4.0***

The bold packages are the ones which should be filtered out.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If a package is already installed it will be skipped by pip anyway.

Comment: If I refactor stuff I lose track what is in which package. I want to automate cleaning up my requirements.txt and don'T see duplicates as a good code quality.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`pipdeptree`](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree) can display the dependencies tree, and for a given package tell you which other package(s) depends on it.

Comment: Specifically: https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree#using-pipdeptree-to-write-requirementstxt-file

Comment: Then, you can use grep to get only top level dependencies: `pipdeptree | grep -e '^\S'`